# Creating a cycle with conditions

Tags: graphs-and-networks, conditional, sorting

I would like to arrange a gift exchange between 5 people, Alice, Bob, Carl, Danny, and Ellen, and I would like the gifts to be passed in a randomly created cycle (B->C->A->D->E->B), for example.

Which is easy enough, just randomly sort the list; but I want to include some conditions. For example, A lives with B so I don't want one passing to the other, or C gave to D last year, so this year I want C to give to anyone else. Things like that

I'm pretty new to coding, so I'm not really sure of the best approach to making these kinds of conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code:

```
allCycles=Map[Prepend[#,a]&,Permutations[{b,c,d,e}]];
oneWay[x_,y_]:={___,x,y,___}|{y,___,x};
twoWay[x_,y_]:=oneWay[x,y]|oneWay[y,x];
```

**Example.** All cycles that exclude a to b, b to a, c to d:

```
DeleteCases[allCycles, twoWay[a,b]|oneWay[c,d]]
```

This gives

```
{{a,c,b,d,e},
 {a,c,b,e,d},
 {a,c,e,b,d},
 {a,d,b,c,e},
 {a,d,b,e,c},
 {a,d,c,b,e},
 {a,d,e,b,c},
 {a,e,b,d,c},
 {a,e,c,b,d},
 {a,e,d,b,c}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set a complete graph:

```
g = VertexReplace[CompleteGraph[5, DirectedEdges -> True], 
   Thread[Range[5] -> {a, b, c, d, e}]];
```

Exclude conditions:

```
g = EdgeDelete[g, {a -> b, b -> a, c -> d} ];
```

Find cycles:

```
FindCycle[g2, {5}, All][[All, All, 1]]
```

> {{a, e, d, b, c}, {a, e, c, b, d}, {a, e, b, d, c}, {a, d, e, b,
> c}, {a, d, c, b, e}, {a, d, b, e, c}, {a, d, b, c, e}, {a, c, e, b,
> d}, {a, c, b, e, d}, {a, c, b, d, e}}

Answer (score 2):

This gives all exchange options (5! or 120):

```
exchanges = Map[Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} -> #] &, Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e}]]
```

But it includes giving gifts to yourself. This excludes those (44 left):

```
e2 = Select[exchanges, FreeQ[#, x_ -> x_] &]
```

This also excludes 'a' giving to 'b' and vice versa (24 left):

```
e3 = Select[e2, And[FreeQ[#, a -> b], FreeQ[#, b -> a]] &]
```

And you can continue this way...

Answer (score 1):

This won't scale well for many people, but it's a start:

```
people = {"Alice", "Bob", "Craig", "Danny", "Egbert"}
```

all chains

```
perms = Permutations[people];
```

all giving cycles

```
giftCycles = 
  Table[MapThread[fromTo[#1][#2] &, {perm, RotateLeft[perm]}], {perm, 
    perms}];

Length[giftCycles]
```

Eliminate particular cases

```
reducedGiftCycles = Select[giftCycles,
   MemberQ[#, 
     fromTo["Danny"]["Craig"] | fromTo["Craig"]["Danny"] | 
      fromTo["Bob"]["Danny"]] &, Infinity
   ];

Length[reducedGiftCycles]

RandomChoice[reducedGiftCycles]
```